# SSIS Connection Error

Tags: sql, ssis, bids

I have the following code written into an SSIS Script Task to connect to my SQL database:

```
 ConnectionManager cm;
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn;
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlComm;

 cm = Dts.Connections["QUAHILSQ03"];

 sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
```

However this line:

```
 sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
```

Returns the following exception:

{"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty simple fix: I had created the QUAHILSQ03 Connection Manager as an OLE DB connection. Simply changed it to ADO.NET and my code worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Seems to me that you are using an OLEDB connection . Acquire connection method on oledb connection manager returns a COM object so you are getting the error .

Try this :

```
   ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["QUAHILSQ03"];
   IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject 
   as IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
   OleDbConnection conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
```

You need to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper` namespace With the above approach you cannot retain the `transaction` .

for more details refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/08/22/accessing-oledb-connection-managers-in-a-script.aspx) article

Comment: And if you chose to go the [ado.net](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/05/use-connections-properly-in-ssis-script.html) route, Todd McDermid's post ought to help you out

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
```

It works for me